# Stencil JSX listener throwing exception

Tags: stenciljs

I am trying to use JSX event listening strategy as describe here:
https://stenciljs.com/docs/events#using-events-in-jsx

however, when I set up my event listener in my JSX i get the following error:

```
Type '{ ref: (el: HTMLElement) => ISubflow; onButtonStateChange:
(ev: CustomEvent<ButtonState>) => void; }' is not assignable to type
 'MyComponentAttributes'. Property 'onButtonStateChange' does
 not exist on type 'MyComponentAttributes'.
```

MyComponent has this event definition:

```
@Event() onButtonStateChange: EventEmitter<ButtonState>;
```

and the JSX looks like this:

```
<my-component
            ref={(el)=> this.currentSubflow = (el as unknown) as ISubflow}
            onButtonStateChange={(ev:CustomEvent<ButtonState>) => this.onButtonStateChanged(ev)} />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh man, this is a sneaky one~!

JSX eventing follows a naming convention! All I had to do was change

```
@Event() onButtonStateChange: EventEmitter<ButtonState>;
```

to

```
@Event() buttonStateChange: EventEmitter<ButtonState>;
```

and the Sencil/JSX stuff prepends the `on` to the event to listen for it!